# Use PC as Web Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, hosting, asp.net-mvc

How can I use my own PC (Windows 7 Home Premium, SQL Server 2008 Express,IIS 7.5) as web server for my ASP.NET MVC Website?

[Update] : I know how to run IIS in Win 7 and locally I can host my web. I wanted to know if it is possible to use a PC as host for websites; I mean a user on the web can write the URL or my IP and access my web?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use PC as Web Server](http://serverfault.com/questions/107805/use-pc-as-web-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up the computer acting as the server with a local static ip address. Forward port 80 requests on your public IP to that computer via your router. If your public IP is dynamic, not static, you may want to use a service such as no-ip.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that all Windows desktop operating systems have limited incoming connections (10 simulaneous connections).

If you can ignore this limitation, the steps would be:

- on your router: forward port 80 TCP to your PC's local IP address
- allow port 80 on your Windows firewall for incoming connections
- from outside, use the IP address your provider assigned to your internet connection or use a service like dyndns.com.